# ffmpeg video stream delay in playback?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, latency, wowza

I'm trying to capture and stream video from a 5MP USB camera using ffmpeg 3.2.2 on Windows.  Here's the command line that I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 320x240 -framerate 30 -i video="HD USB Camera" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -g 60 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.100:10000
```

The destination for my stream (an Ubuntu box on the same subnet) is running ffplay via:

```
ffplay -i udp://127.0.0.1:10000
```

This works but the video stream seems like it's delayed by 8 - 10 seconds.  It's my understanding that the destination can't begin displaying the stream until it receives an I-frame so I tried specifying a GOP value of 60 thinking that this would cause an I-frame to be inserted every 2 seconds (@ 30 FPS).

The Windows machine that's doing the transcoding is running an i7-3840QM @ 2.80GHz and has 32 GB RAM.  FFmpeg appears to be using very little CPU (like 2%) so it doesn't seem like it's CPU bound.  Just as a test, I tried ingesting an MP4 file and not doing any transcoding (`ffmpeg -re -i localFile.mp4 -c copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.100:10000`) but it still takes several seconds before the stream is displayed on the Ubuntu system.

On a related note, I'm also evaluating a trial version of the Wowza Streaming Engine server and when I direct my ffmpeg stream to Wowza, I get the same 8 - 10 second delay before the Wowza test player starts playing it back.  For what it's worth, once the stream starts playing, it seems to be running fine (other than the fact that everything is "behind" by several seconds).

I'm new to video streaming so I might be missing something obvious here but can anyone tell me what might be causing this delay or suggest how I might further troubleshoot the problem?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try setting this values:

> analyzeduration integer (input)
>
> Specify how many microseconds are analyzed to probe the input. A
>   higher value will enable detecting more accurate information, but will
>   increase latency. It defaults to 5,000,000 microseconds = 5 seconds.
>
> probesize integer (input)
>
> Set probing size in bytes, i.e. the size of the data to analyze to get
>   stream information. A higher value will enable detecting more
>   information in case it is dispersed into the stream, but will increase
>   latency. Must be an integer not lesser than 32. It is 5000000 by
>   default.

[FFmpeg docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html)